# Unreliable QEMU guest agent responses

Tags: kvm, qemu

I have a script for automatic backups of my KVMs. Before taking a LVM snapshot I'm trying to freeze the filesystems of the KVM with the QEMU guest agent. It works good most of the time but randomly I don't receive a direct answer from the guest agent or I receive messages like the following when running fs-freeze:

```
Guest agent is not responding: Guest agent not available for now
```

... or different error messages. The problem is that the filesystems are frozen anyway. So when my backup script stops at this point (because it expects proper exit status/code) my KVM will be frozen and will therefore be unreachable until it is thawed again!

Is there an alternative way to freeze the filesystems of a KVM? I'd like to access the qemu "console" for these KVMs directly and run the fs-freeze manually.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I can simply use the "fsfreeze" command that comes with the util-linux package:

```
Usage:
 fsfreeze [options] <mount point>

Options:
 -h, --help        this help
 -f, --freeze      freeze the filesystem
 -u, --unfreeze    unfreeze the filesystem

For more information see fsfreeze(8).
```